# When did Kagami first attend a Comiket?

Tags: lucky-star

In Episode 12, the Hiiragi twins accompany Konata to a Comiket. While it is Tsukasa's first time there, Kagamin has apparently visited before (with Konata). Is this earlier visit (sans Tsukasa) covered in the anime? How about the manga?

Screenshots (clickable) from E12:

From ~1:50 where Konata tries to trick Miyuki into coming along:

[image: Opening scene]

The following snapshots are from ~3:30.

[image: First timer]

[image: Second timer]

Comment: Where does she mention that Kagami has been to Comiket before? Looking over the a.f.k. script, when both Kagami and Tsukasa was complaining about the even, Konata says "I figured it would be a rough schedule for a first-timer".

Comment: @JonLin Screenies added.

Comment: @coleopterist went through the manga volumes again now that I've seen the screen captures. There's still no mention of it though. Edited my answer

Answer (score 4):

As far as the manga is concerned, episode 12 ***is*** also the first time Kagami has been to Comiket. Or at least a previous visit isn't shown.

Kagami has been to the gamers store with Konata several times, so it wouldn't be a surprise if she managed to drag her along to Comiket.

In volume 1 of the manga, Kagami exclaims "I've never been to that". There are no Comikets shown between this scene and the one that Kagami arrives at.

[image: ls]

As a point of note though, new Lucky Star strips were occasionally released at comic conventions around Japan. If you were convinced that Kagami had been there before, perhaps she and Konata appeared at one of the Comikets 'IRL' before Tsukasa.